# Google calendar api: book a user calendar from an admin account

Tags: google-calendar-api

We have a google apps account for our domain.  In my application, I have, in python, authenticated with one of our admin accounts.

I can add events to the admin account calendar just fine.

Is it possible, with the admin credentials, to add an event to a user's calendar?  I can add an event to the admin's calendar and add the user as a participant, but that incorrectly makes the admin account the "organizer", which is not what we want.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have admin credentials, you can use the email of the user as the calendarId in the [insert call](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)